# How to send carriage return over telnet?

Tags: tcp, console, client, telnet

I am using Ubuntu telnet client.
I am trying to send 2 lines over the telnet connection that I have made.

For example:

```
> telnet en.wikipedia.org 80
  GET /wiki/Main_Page http/1.1   <CR>                            // line 1
  Host: en.wikipedia.org         <CR>                            // line 2
  <CR>
```

where CR stands for carriage return.
The problem is after typing line 1, press CR , that line will be sent over the telnet connection. I can not be able to send line 2 immediately after that.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the <CR> with a '\', i.e., GET /wiki/Main_Page http/1.1 \<CR>

Comment: It is a bit late to point this out but - like @Mark hinted in his comment - you MUST not send just a `\r` character on it's own. if you are sending a normal end of line you must send a `\r\n` (Carriage-Return + New Line) pair of characters - if you intend to send only a Carriage-Return to move the *current* position to the start of the line **without advancing to the next line** then you must send `\r\0` i.e. a Carriage-Return and then a Null character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are operating in a Telnet client, sending a newline or carriage return control code to the client, will send it directly to the host.

The easiest way to do what you want would be to copy/paste the HTTP GET request from another text editor, so that the newlines are embedded in the text.

Comment: to clarify, it seems that pressing the enter-key when in a telnet session will always send either `\r<NULL>` or `\r\n`.  The only way to transmit just `\n` at the end of a line is to copy/paste it from somewhere else like an editor.

Answer (score 42):

You can set the crlf option in telnet. You can do this by, during your telnet session, typing the escape character (^]), and then "toggle crlf". A perhaps cleaner way is to specify this before making the connection:

```
$ telnet
telnet> toggle crlf
Will send carriage returns as telnet <CR><LF>.
telnet> open mailhost smtp
```

Comment: On windows 8.1 you should use "set crlf" instead of "toggle crlf"

Answer (score 2):

Try Ctrl+Shift+Enter
I tried on Mac OS Mojave Terminal.

Comment: Thanks! That should be the answer. Works for Ubuntu too

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is this.

For windows users, it is well known that cmd is case-insensitive by default.

But in windows, the editing interface of telnet is case sensitive!

Same for unix, Ubuntu, etc.

If you enter: GET /wiki/Main_Page http/1.1, you will get the wrong result.

If you enter: GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1, you will get the result you want.

This telnet problem took me hours, damn it.

Comment: This is not a telnet problem. This is you not understanding the HTTP protocol.