# JMeter - Execute command over telnet using beanshell

Tags: memcached, jmeter, telnet, beanshell

I'm trying to write a jmeter sampler in beanshell to execute a memcached telnet interface command, specifically flush_all. I need this to clear the cache after each test as it causes tests in quick succession to fail.

I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
telnet.connect( "memcachedServer.dev", 11211 );

//InputStream in = telnet.getInputStream(); 
PrintStream out = new PrintStream( telnet.getOutputStream() );

out.println("flush_all\r");
out.println("quit\r");

telnet.disconnect();
```

It seems to execute with no problems but the cache is not cleared. I have tried the code with and without the "\r" but neither way works.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Any logs on the memcache server?  Full output from your program may help.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason for not using [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler)?

1. Add TCP Sampler to your test plan (where you need to flush caches)
2. Configure host and port
3. Put the following lines into "Text to send" area:

   ```
   flush_all${CR}${LF}
   quit${CR}${LF}
   ```
4. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the TCP Sampler
5. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put("LF",URLDecoder.decode("%0D", "ASCII"));
   vars.put("CR",URLDecoder.decode("%0A", "ASCII"));
   ```

See [How To Send Control Characters Using The JMeter TCP Sampler?](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733759-How-to-Send-Control-Characters-Using-the-JMeter-TCP-Sampler-) guide for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

scripting / emulateing a terminal can be problematic. 
Your code is executing, and printing the command "flush_all" but it seems like the enter/newline command is not being processed.

There are 2 options that might work for you

Here is an article on how to send the carriage return over telnet.

[How to send carriage return over telnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159342/how-to-send-carriage-return-over-telnet)

Or, you may have more luck with the SSH jmeter plugin, which I think is built in to the extra libs, but if not i can send you a link. 
 this will allow you to log in, and execute a command in a given dir, its simple and pretty clean

Comment: Please do cite the relevant parts of that link, in case the link breaks

Comment: Sorry, good point Johannes, enter-key in telnet will send either \r<NULL> or \r\n
or set how telnet sends the enter key by switching it to <CR><LF> by using the telnet command "toggle crlf" before you make your connection