# Jmeter and MemCached Sets and Gets

Tags: java, jmeter, memcached

So apologies if what I ask is trivial but I am experimenting with Memcached and Jmeter.   I have a Memcached server setup (as far as I can tell) and am able to make telnet requests to it via telnet *IP PORT* and additionally set and get using commands set and get appropriately.

Now point me to a different application if perhaps this is the wrong choice; but my understanding was that Jmeter should allow me to pound the server with equivalent Set and Get requests.

Unfortunately the experimental platform is a remote linux PC running Rockylinux which is similar to CentOS / RedHat to my understanding (I didn't set this part up); and as a result I do not have a GUI to launch while on the Linux PC.  I have however opened Jmeter up on my local PC on windows and understand I should be able to send the test file over and run it.

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403462/jmeter-execute-command-over-telnet-using-beanshell) to try to setup a TCP sampler and set the "text to send" field as below; after doing the additional step in the link regarding the precompiler.

```html
set tutorialspoint 0 900 9${CR}${LF}
memcached${CR}${LF}
quit${CR}${LF}
```

Running the above as a headless jmeter session doesn't generate any errors called  [./jmeter -n -t "Sample.jmx" -l testresults.jtl"] but when I connect via telnet I'm also not seeing the value for the key "tutorialspoint" get updated.  When manually doing the get and set I am seeing updates.  Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?  Checking the log indicates ResponseCode 200 OK as expected.  Is there a good method to debug something in a Headless setup?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is using [Memcached Java Client library](https://github.com/couchbase/spymemcached)

1. Download [spymemcached-2.12.3.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/spy/spymemcached/2.12.3/spymemcached-2.12.3.jar) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or any other location in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your test plan and use the following code snippets:

   - `def client = new net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress('your-memcached-host', your-memcached-port))` - for connecting to the server
   - `client.set('tutorialspoint', 900, 'memcached').done` to write `memcached` to the `tutorialspoint` key for 15 minutes
   - `client.get('tutorialspoint')` - to read the value of `tutorialspoint` key
   - `client.shutdown()` - to disconnect

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Demo:

[image]