# Telnet Response contains \r\n in the middle after ~50 characters

Tags: c#, linux, telnet

I am doing a telnet connection to the Linux device (using c# code) and execute some commands and in which the command has more than 50 characters. The command is been executed successfully however the telnet response contains a \r\n after ~65 characters which cause the issue.

The script is expecting the response as full command in one line and the output of the command in the next line. However I am getting something like below:

command sent: /root/supplicants/wpa_cli -i p2p0 p2p_peer 00:11:22:33:44:55

Response: /root/supplicants/wpa_cli -i p2p0 p2p_peer 00:1
1:22:33:44:55
00:11:22:33:44:55

How to fix this issue? Why is it adding the \r\n after certain characters?

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` in a C# string, means a new line (there's a description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) too of these). I think what might be happening is that telnet always gives responses formatted as a line with a set maximum length. Could you try adding something to the script which reformats the response, by removing all occurrences of `\r\n`?

E.g. You can replace these by a blank string, using `String.Replace`

[EDIT]: I don't know if it's possible to request a response with a different line length. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159342/how-to-send-carriage-return-over-telnet) that there's a `toggle clrf` option with Telnet, but that might be just for sending a request.

Comment: Is it possible to change the maximum length of the telnet response? if so, how to do it?