# Error sending command to Beanstalkd from telnet

Tags: telnet, beanstalkd

Whenn I send the following sequence via telnet I get EXPECTED_CRLF:

```
$ telnet localhost 11300
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
put 0 0 1 4 
68 6f 6c 61
EXPECTED_CRLF
UNKNOWN_COMMAND
```

I thought, when I press "Enter" inside telnet, it will be send an "CR LF" (https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/31.htm)

Beanstalkd Protocol here: https://github.com/beanstalkd/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

I tried toggling crlf like @Alister Bulman said, but it didn't work:

```
$ telnet
telnet> toggle crlf
Will send carriage returns as telnet <CR><LF>.
telnet> open localhost 11300
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
put 0 0 1 4
68 6f 6c 61
EXPECTED_CRLF
UNKNOWN_COMMAND
```

Comment: What client are you using, and which  OS/distribution?

Comment: Telnet as client (Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/22974813/6216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was: you can send a text without to encode it in bytes. For the text "hola" is right 4 Bytes, but for "68 6f 6c 61" had to be "11" bytes length.
I misunderstood the protocol, since it is described as "a sequence of bytes" for `<data>`. Indeed the TCP delivery is a stream of bytes!

> `- <data> is the job body -- a sequence of bytes of length <bytes> from the    previous line.`

So the correct commands are:

```
$ telnet
telnet> open localhost 11300
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
put 0 0 1 4
hola
INSERTED 1
put 0 0 1 11
68 6f 6c 61
INSERTED 2
```